# Complex (?) LineSeries itemsource object

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am trying to instantiate multiple line series using the same itemsource object by defining adifferent DataFieldY for each LineSeries Object.

I've got this working at first when i had and object with multiple properties like

```
class simple
{
   double time;
   double value1;
   double value2;
}
```

That way I could set the DataFieldY in one graph to `DataFieldY="value1"`  for example. 
Now comes my problem, my class is slightly different since it comes from a Mongo database. I looks something like this:

```
class complex
{
   double timestamp;
   Backward b;
   Forward f;
}
class Backward 
{
   double backValue;
}
class Forward
{
   double forwardValue;
}
```

There are other variables of course and the hierarchy actually runs one level deeper. But this should work as an example.

What is the string that I need to add now at the `DataFieldY` considering that `ItemSource` is now equals to `ObservableCollection<Complex>`?

Also is there a way, maybe using reflection, for me to initialize all the line series using a `foreach` loop?

```
foreach(var s in Magic(complex))
{
    var ln = new LineSeries()
    ln.ItemSource = complexCollection
    ln.DataFieldT = s;
}
```

Maybe I am trying to do this in the wrong way too :)

Cheers

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about. Do you mean how to specify the property path in your bindings defined in XAML?

Comment: Did you try to set the DataFieldY property to "b.backValue" or "f.ForwardValue"? If this doesn't work you are out of luck using the DataFieldY property with your current types.

Comment: @dymanoid No, I have only the model bound in the XAML. The series are created in code. I want to know if there is a way to define the path for the Y value if the object in the itemSource is similar to the `Complex`above

Comment: @mm8 I was ready to say that it didn't worked until it hit me! I had to add {get;} :D Thanks! `DataFieldY = "backward.enclosure1.pressure";` works like a charm

Comment: I'll add an answer soon

Comment: @mm8 any suggestions on how I can drill down the class using reflection, or not, to get the paths for the DataFields?

Comment: You already have the paths, don't you?

Comment: Yes, because I have the class itself. But here are ~30 variables I was wondering if there was a way to create the LineSeries and assign the paths inside a loop (without me creating a list with the paths manually). This will take more time than if I write the list :)

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `b` and `f` into *public properties*:

```
class complex
{
    ...
    public Backward b { get; set; }
    public Forward f { get; set; }
}
```

You should then be able to specify a nested property path, e.g.:

```
DataFieldY = "b.backValue";
```